# how to determine maximum route cost in a n high numeric pyramid

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I've got a numeric pyramid like this

```
       7
      4 8
     1 8 9
    2 4 6 7
   4 6 7 4 9
  4 9 7 3 8 8

routes: 32
```

every number indexed by how powerful in its line.

```
 0 ( 9 => 1 ) 1 ( 8 => 5 ) 2 ( 8 => 4 ) 3 ( 7 => 2 ) 4 ( 4 => 0 ) 5 ( 3 => 3 )
 0 ( 9 => 4 ) 1 ( 7 => 2 ) 2 ( 6 => 1 ) 3 ( 4 => 3 ) 4 ( 4 => 0 )
 0 ( 7 => 3 ) 1 ( 6 => 2 ) 2 ( 4 => 1 ) 3 ( 2 => 0 )
 0 ( 9 => 2 ) 1 ( 8 => 1 ) 2 ( 1 => 0 )
 0 ( 8 => 1 ) 1 ( 4 => 0 )
 0 ( 7 => 0 )
```

in this pyramid there are 2^(n-1) routes (you can go 2 way form each number)
If the pyramid high this low, it's easy you can calculate all the routes, and compare to eachother. But if you have an 50 high pyramid with 562949953421312 routes, the problem little bit more difficult.

I thoght I start from the bottom beginning from the most powerful numbers, but soon i realized, the max route cost ain't necesserly start or end up in big numbers.

Then I thought maybe secoundary indexes (where can you go futher from a number) will help, but I didin't even implement that becouse I assumed its still uses much resources and not optimal.

And now i'm confused how to restart thinking about this problem... any advice appreciated

Comment: This sounds like a job for... Dynamic Programming Man! However, I don't fully understand your problem, so I'm not going to sketch the DP algorithm for you.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble understanding your question, and not just because of the English. You seem to have a graph problem, maybe you should read up on that and state your question in terms of graphs, edges, and nodes.

Comment: Thanx, I'm aware of graphs, but somehow I thought I can exclude them. And sorry for my English, i thought you guys will understand it :) I didn't use as much as I have to.

Comment: "every number indexed by how powerful in its line" does not make any sense.  Perhaps write it in your native tongue so that someone else could try to translate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of your pyramid as a tree with the root at the top of the pyramid: I think you want the route with the maximum cost from the root to any of the leaf nodes (bottom of the pyramid). OK, it's not actually a tree, because a node may have two parents, in fact you can get to a node at level `i` from at most two nodes at level `i-1`.

Anyway, I think you can compute the route with the maximum cost by using dynamic programming. Let me rewrite your data in a matrix like way:

```
7 
4 8 
1 8 9 
2 4 6 7 
4 6 7 4 9 
4 9 7 3 8 8
```

and let the missing elements of the matrix be 0. Let's call this matrix `v` (for values). Now you can build a matrix `c` (for costs) where `c(i,j)` is the maximum cost for reaching the tree node at position `(i,j)`. You can compute it with this recurrence:

`c(i,j) = v(i,j) + max{ c(i-1,j-1), c(i-1,j) }`

where `c(h,k)` is 0 when you get to a position out of the matrix. Essentially we say that the maximum cost for getting to node at position `(i,j)` is the cost of the node itself plus the maximum between the costs of getting to its two possible parents at level `i-1`.

Here is `c` for your example:

```
7     
11 15    
12 23 24   
14 27 30 31  
18 33 37 35 40 
22 42 44 40 48 48
```

For instance, let's take `i=3, j=2`:

```
c(3,2) = v(3,2) + max{ c(2,1), c(2,2) }
       = 6      + max{ 23    , 24     }
       = 30
```

From `c` you see that the most expensive rout costs 48 (and you have two of them).

Comment: nice job man! I did write the exact same solution except the matrix part, but thanx for your time :) dynamic programming the best!

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way is to go bottom up and you have O(N) compexity. This case you do not need dynamic programming or recursion. Just compose another tree where number at higher level is max of numbers of lower layer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a).

I believe Dijkstra's is more accurate than A*, but slower.

Comment: A* requires an admissible heuristic, basically a way to guess the distance to the goal. I don't think there is one for this problem.

Comment: You can just take the greedy approach there.  Once again, this will not be correct 100% of the time but will be much faster in a large graph.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers represent the cost to travel between 2 nodes of a graph, then [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) will find the shortest path.

Answer (score 0):

I think that even if you use the Suggested Dijkstra's Algorithm, you still have to test every route. First of all because there is no single starting and end point, but there are 50 starting points for the end point. So the algorithm has to be tested 50 times.

And because every option has 2 paths, there is no way of skipping one. You can never rule out a path untill you are at the very end.

So I dont think there is a quicker way to find the longest path (so not the shortest as in Dijkstra's Algorithm) then to test all routes.

Answer (score 0):

as you can Consider the tree a DAG Do a Topological sort then relax(relax to the max not min) each edge as they are in the topological sort O(E+V) .

Comment: could you further clarify your answer? Maybe an example?

Comment: @Origin You can expect each number as a graph edge , as I am supposed to get the maximum route and I cannot look back , the pyramid turns out to be a DAG , doing a DFS to get the topological sort then use it to get the shortest path of the graph you can get it faster than the Dynamic programming solution