# two multidimensional array handling in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got an array like this

```
[["1"], ["2","3"]]
```

In the beginning I had this algorithm

```
maxarray = []
i = 0
m = array.count
while i < m do
  x = 0
  s = array[i].count
  while x < s do
    maxarray[i][x] = (Integer(array[i][x]) + [Integer(maxarray[i-1][x-1]), Integer(maxarray[i-1][x])].max)
    x+=1 
  end
  i+=1
end
```

the error was this:

```
`<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

so I thought maybe the array indexes goes wrong so I extended my algorithm

```
maxarray = []
i = 0
m = array.count
while i < m do
  x = 0
  s = array[i].count
  while x < s do
    if i-1 < 0 
        item2 = 0
    elsif i-1 < 0 && x-1 < 0 
        item1 = 0
    else item1 = maxarray[i-1][x-1] 
         item2 = maxarray[i-1][x] 
    end
    maxarray[i][x] = (Integer(array[i][x]) + [Integer(item1), Integer(item2)].max)
    x+=1 
  end
  i+=1
end
```

but now i have an different error:

```
`Integer': can't convert nil into Integer (TypeError)
```

how can prevent this error and run the script?

Comment: why not using: `maxarray.each do |cur_x| (do_something) end` You are not using Ruby powers here :)

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to do rather than give your current solution ...

Comment: @Chris McCauley it's right in the middle `maxarray = (Integer(array[i][x]) + [Integer(item1), Integer(item2)].max)` :)

Comment: sry I misspeld this... `maxarray[i][x] = (Integer(array[i][x]) + [Integer(item1), Integer(item2)].max)`

Comment: Yes, use `each` instead of reimplementing it poorly. No, don't switch from `[]` to `Array.new`. @Mikee: Chris asked for an explanation, not a copy/paste.

Comment: Sry this explains to me... I want to rewrite this solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636413/how-to-determine-maximum-route-cost-in-a-n-high-numeric-pyramid) in ruby. And why did you say poorly implementing?

Comment: Rather than giving your code, which has unexplained variables like `tomb`, state what you want to do.

Comment: @Mkikee, "this explains to me": it doesn't matter if it explains it to **you**, it only matters if it explains it to the person who asked for an explanation. If you don't want help your helpers, you probably won't be helped. I said poorly because you reimplemented `#each` yourself using a while loop and a counter but it is broken. I think a broken implementation is a poor one. I also think an unnecessary reimplementation of a perfectly good and useful basic Ruby method is a poor one.

Comment: @sawa sry i miss spelld that also... @Rein I told you sry, and that's why I'm here to fix **this** code/loop

Comment: Ok, so start answering our questions.

Comment: I want that the maxarray array filled with the data instead of giving this error. I think solution is that if I got nil i have to change it to 0

Comment: but if do that I've got a similar error as the first time ``<main>': undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: I can't help you if the best you can describe the problem is to say that you want something 'filled with the data'. This is worrisome, as communicating effectively is a foundational skill for programmers.

Comment: I've inspected this algorithm, the problem is that it accesses elements out of array bounds, that gets `nil`. Outside the scope of the problem it solves it can't be fixed.

Comment: And about **a half** of the first version of this algorithm is a reimplementation of `each_with_index`, something easy to make mistakes with.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't `flatten` the array and make your computing? Certainly it will make your function simplier.

Comment: It looks like some task with dynamic programming involved, it relies on multiple dimensions of the dataset for keeping code simpler. It's guesswork, since even the author fails to explain his intent.